# Changing color of the div that is outside parent div of the div that should trigger action

Tags: css, css-selectors, css-animations

Please check this first to understand question:
http://jsfiddle.net/830b4rLw/3/

HTML:

```
<div id="nav">
<div id="box1"></div>
<div id="box2"></div>
</div>
<div id="header"></div>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    background-color: #606;
}

#nav {
    background-color: #f00;
    height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
}

#header {
    height: 300px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #00f;
}

#box1 {
    height: 30px;
    width: 20px;
    float: left;
    background-color: #0f0;
}

#box2 {
    height: 30px;
    width: 50px;
    background-color: #000;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 5px;
}

@keyframes a {
    0%{}
    100% {background-color: #fff;}
    }

#box1:hover + #box2{
        animation: a 2s;
        animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
```

On linked jsfiddle when you hover box1 (green box), box2 changes its color.

Now what I want to do is;

First case scenario: when you hover box1, I want to change background color of #header (blue box).

Second case secenario, I want to change body background (which is on this example currently purple) color when you hover #box1.

So what I am asking here, I want either change background color of a div that is not next to another, and does not share same parent. And In second case scenario, I want to hover a div (that is inside another div) to change background color of a  element.

Please read: I do not want to use any javascript!

Thank you all for responses, any additional information and hints about this section is very welcome!

Comment: Both scenarios can’t be accomplished using current CSS, as there is no such thing as a parent selector. You would need to make changes to the HTML structure.

Comment: Basically what I am trying to do here is, I have a website which should change theme color by clicking on one of the color boxes that are in nav. And these color changes happen outside nav. (elements after nav). Which HTML structure change would you suggest? I tried many, and all of them failed.

Comment: With a few exceptions, such as radio buttons and checkboxes, state cannot be changed with HTML alone. I suggest looking into the jQuery library, which makes this type of thing simple.

Comment: You would need a structure where the elements you want to affect are siblings on the same level after your trigger elements. (So you could “fake” your body background by positioning such an element behind all content.)

Comment: But what @isherwood just mentioned constitutes an additional problem. There is one more thing though, and that could be used to even change properties of body by clicking on a descendant element of it – anchor links and the `:target` pseudo class.

Comment: @CBroe  Thank you for idea about faking it, it worked, I am very grateful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question, here is solution:

You can use label-input technique.

HTML Codes:

label

input type="radio"  OR  input type="checkbox"

This solution also makes it onclick instead of hover so you don't need to use JavaScript onclick function, its double problem solver.

http://jsfiddle.net/69m1mmmk/1/

so label, the thing we click and modify to look alike as we want is in a nav:

```
<div id="nav">
<label class="color-box" id="color-box1" for="color-box-input1"></label>
<label class="color-box" id="color-box2" for="color-box-input2"></label>
</div>
```

however radio-buttons are hidden and they are in the same parent div as background div. (read @CBroe 's  comment on question post to understand more about background div) or just inspect JS fiddle code to understand what I mean.
So when you click on label you will trigger radio buttons that are on the other side of the website and animation will work just fine!

```
#color-box-input2:checked ~ #choose-color-bg {
animation: color2 2s;
animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
```